# False if Statement Still Executes

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the Xcode 6 Beta, and I have used this exact code in another class, setup up in the same way. For some reason it doesn't want to work here. When I touch an SKNode, I grab its name, and compare the name to two strings, if it matches either of them, I execute some code. See below.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let node: SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))

        if node.name == "body" || "face" {
            self.childNodeWithName("face").runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(6.283, duration: 0.75))
        }
    }
}
```

As I said before, this exact code work flawlessly everywhere else I have used it, but no matter which node I press, the code inside the if statement will be run. Yes, I have printed out the names of nodes I am touching, and they do not match. Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer to Swift manual about using string comparators in if-clauses. The error is in this line: 'if node.name == "body" || "face"'.

Comment: Okay, I will take a look, but any idea why this has worked several dozen other times in the same project?

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant

```
if node.name == "body" || node.name == "face" {
```

It would be more clear with parentheses, you are doing:

```
if (node.name == "body") || ("face") {
```

And `"face"` is `true`, which probably is a bug on Apple's side as `String` does not conform to `LogicValue` so you should not be able to test it like that. Probably the literal gets interpreted as something else conforming to `LogicValue` e.g. a `CString`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` is idiomatically expressed as a `switch` with

```
switch node.name {
  case "body", "face":
    self.childNodeWithName ...
  default: break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should

`if node.name == "body" || node.name == "face" {  //change this statement`

replace this in your function

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let node: SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))

        if node.name == "body" || node.name == "face" {  //change this statement
            self.childNodeWithName("face").runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(6.283, duration: 0.75))
        }
    }
}
```